# Помогите составить алгоритм подбора значения

Tags: алгоритм, битовые-операции

Необходимо составить алгоритм, принимающий на вход строго положительное n и выводящий k, такое что 2^k ≤ n и 2^k+1 > n

Помогите составить алгоритм, учусь на первом курсе бакалавриата компьютерных наук.

Самым простым способом с функциями If и / или While. Не первой же неделе нам задали такое. Не понимаю с какой стороны подходить к решению этого вопроса. Объясните пожалуйста доступным языком, пошагово.

Comment: Для начала, вы бы сформулировали задание. `2^k ≤ n and 2^k+1 > n`, боюсь огорчить вас, понятным описанием не является. Затем, мой хрустальный шар подсказывает, что вам нужна функция логарифм по основанию 2. А за объяснением почему стоит обратиться к лектору, он наверняка это объяснял на первой же лекции (тема была небось «двоичная система счисления», да?)

Comment: Точно нужно обойтись без логарифмов, этого даже не проходили и на лекции об этом не было речи. Можно даже алгоритм построить отдельно для каждой левой и правой частей. И допустим k = 2 n = 7

Comment: Вам нужно вычислить k или 2^k

Comment: Sketch an algorithm that takes as input a strictly positive integer n and outputs an integer k such that: 2^k ≤ n and 2^k+1 > n                                                   Извиняюсь за английский, учусь в Англии

Comment: А в чем проблема-то? И да, в условии нет ничего про запрет логарифмов.

Comment: Скобки для ясности уточните: может, таки `2^(k+1) > n` ?

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации с описанием конкретных проблем.

Answer (score 5):

1. Числа в компьютере хранятся в двоичной форме (как последовательности нулей и единиц), поэтому например 13 будет выглядеть как 1101.
2. Делению на 2 соответствует операция сдвига вправо (>>) соответственно умножению сдвиг влево (<<).
3. Степени числа 2 таким образом соответствуют цифре 1 в позиции k (степень числа) и 0 в остальных позициях.
4. Для получения k нам нужно сдвигать вправо число n до тех пор пока оно превышает 0, инкременируя при этом k от (-1).

КОД

```
unsigned int n = 1223456789;
int k = -1;

for (unsigned int i = n; i > 0; k++, i >>= 1);
```

Пошагово:

```
1. Задаете число n=[ваше число] и k = -1
2. Проверяете n>0
3. True
   3.1 Увеличиваем k на 1
   3.2 Делим n на 2 (целочислено) или, что то же самое, применяем операцию сдвига на 1
   3.3 Переходим к шагу 2
4. False Конец алгоритма. Выводим данные.
```

Comment: Что выдаст ваш алгоритм при N=1? Ответом в этом случае будет множество целых чисел от -INF до 0 включительно.

Comment: @ВиталийОбидейко 0 (что является правильным ответом), n^0 = 1

Comment: n^-1 = 0.5 0.5+1>1 0.5<=1

Comment: @ВиталийОбидейко - вы алгоритм то прочитали, -1 он выдаст только при n<=0 которые невозможны по условию

Comment: при N=1 наши ограничения превращаются в 2^k ≤ 1 and 2^k+1 > 1. Затем после подстановки K=-1  => 2^(-1) ≤ 1 and 2^(-1)+1 > 1 => 0.5 ≤ 1 and 0.5+1 > 1. Все верно, ч.т.д. K=-1 тоже верный ответ.

Comment: @ВиталийОбидейко, Не читаете... При n=1 2^0 >= 1 и 2^1 > 1. Где вы берете свои значения мне не понятно

Comment: Вам на вход подается N, а как ответ надо дать K, так вот я вам и объясняю, что в таком случае K может быть не только 0!!!!

Comment: @ВиталийОбидейко - log1 всегда равняется 0. Вот если б мы в эту функцию подали 0, но это противоречит условиям задачи

Answer (score 2):

Для условий `2^k ≤ n` и `2^(k+1) > n` вам достаточно найти старший ненулевой бит (его позицию) в двоичной записи числа `n`.

**Алгоритм**: двигаемся от старших битов к младшим, пока не наткнёмся на первую единицу.

1. задать начальное значение битовой позиции - старшее, которое позволяют язык и система – `64-1` или `32-1` (или 30, если 32-битная система и целые со знаком);
2. в цикле сравнивать с нулем значение битовой операции "И" между заданным числом и числом, двоичная запись которого состоит из одной единицы в текущей позиции;
3. если ноль – мы еще не дошли до старшей единицы. Уменьшаем текущую позицию на 1. Повтор цикла.
4. если не ноль – в текущей позиции найдена первая (старшая) единица.
   Текущая позиция – ответ.

Пример ф-ии на JavaScript, который, к сожалению, ограничен 31 битом для битовых операций:

```
function MSB(n) {
    var bit = 31; // 30..0
    while( bit > 0   &&  !( n & (1<<--bit)));
    return bit;
}
```

[Рабочий пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454786/)

Answer (score 0):

Для 2^K ≤ N и (2^K)+1 > N 
Алгоритм очень простой. На вход принимаем положительное целое N. На выходе должны получить целочисленное K. Так вот, если N не является степенью 2, то ответа нет, а если N является степенью 2, то ответ сама степень. Вам осталось только проверять является ли N степенью 2, и если является, то находить какой именно. Алгоритмов таких проверок много и их просто найти.
Пример проверки является ли число степенью 2 на с++:

```
int isPow2(int a) {
  return !(a&(a-1));
}
```

Найти какая именно степень можно делить число в цикле:

```
int k=0;
while(n!=1){
    k++;
    n/=2;
}
```

### upd

Так как по условию N целое и не отрицательные т.е. N>=1, то для N = 1 ответов будет бесконечное множество -INF < K <=0, а во всех остальных случаях будет так, как я написал выше.

Comment: Код у вас в принципе правильный, но по моему вы решаете не ту задачу. Зачем например вам функция isPow2. Перечитайте условие - что то вы не то накрутили в простой как мычание задаче.

Comment: Sketch an algorithm that takes as input a strictly positive integer n and outputs an integer k such that: 2^k ≤ n and 2^k+1 > n. Задача простая, но вы дали на нее неправильный ответ. Весь смысл в том, что условие удовлетворяют лишь такие K, при которых 2^K = N при N>1, а при N=1 я уже описал в ответе.

Comment: isPow2 проверяет является ли число степенью 2-ки

Comment: Первая неделя изучения компьютерных наук - вы серьезно думаете, что студентов станут запутывать, по факту в задаче просят найти степень двойки ближайшей к числу n

Comment: @Mirdin, все может быть, задача очень простая, больше на логику. Проверьте ваш алгоритм по отношению к ограничениям, при N=7, я уверен, что ваш K не выполнит условие 2^k ≤ n and 2^k+1 > n

Comment: Мы с вами просто решаем разные задачи, я лично там вижу 2^(k+1) > n, потому что на первой недели особого смысла в (2^k)+1 > n нет. Но да, ТС должен уточнить это у своего преподавателя

Comment: @Mirdin, Не подумал, просто линейная запись 2^k+1=(2^k)+1, по крайней мере так везде, где только я не видел. интересно за что меня минусуют)))

Comment: @Mirdin тут вы правы, я лично там вижу 2^(k+1) > n

Comment: Вы когда нибудь видели, как в учебнике математики пишется степень и как эта степень записывается в рядах? Просто потерян верхний регистр

Comment: @Mirdin, согласитесь в учебнике с верхним регистром скобочек не надо, а тут это было не очевидно!

Comment: @ВиталийОбидейко - Допустим вы преподаватель, первая неделя обучения, какую из двух задач вы зададите студентам?

Comment: @Mirdin, та, что я решал, с подвохом, она интереснее IMHO)))

Answer (score 0):

Очищаем ненулевые биты с конца, пока они не кончатся. Если кончились, возрвращаем предыдущее значение (с одним единичным битом).

```
function f(n) {
  while (n & n-1)
    n &= n - 1;

  return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ищем k из условия 2<sup>k</sup> <= n < 2<sup>k+1</sup> для k < 32.
На каждой итерации уточняется положение старшего бита до полуслова, байта, тетрады, диады и позиции:

```
k =  (n > 65535) ? 16 : 0; 
if ((n>>k) > 255)  k += 8; 
if ((n>>k) >  15)  k += 4;   
if ((n>>k) >   3)  k += 2;
if ((n>>k) >   1)  k += 1;
```